# Where do I place jetty.xml

Tags: eclipse, jetty, embedded-jetty

Where do I need to place `jetty.xml`, in case of embedded Jetty? 
`jetty-web` is placed inside `WEB-INF` and it is loaded automatically. I tried to put there jetty.xml, but it failed to load (it does not see it). I am using `mvn jetty:run` to run the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their WIKI example doesn't work?  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

```
public class FileServerXml {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Resource fileserver_xml = Resource.newSystemResource("fileserver.xml");
       XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(fileserver_xml.getInputStream());
       Server server = (Server)configuration.configure();
       server.start();
       server.join();
   }
}
```

It sounds like you need to restructure your jetty.xml in any event.

Comment: I do not  have main function.

Comment: My bad. It was included somewhere else.